# Cyclic Component dependency in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

In order to create a nested form structure, I created two Components: `controls` and `control`. (There are multiple version of `control`.)

The basic structure of my views:

```
<custom-form>
  <controls>
    <custom-control></custom-control>
  <controls>
</custom-form>
```

The problem is, that `<custom-control>` in some occasions, should have a nested `<controls>`, thus causing cyclic dependency.

Both `<custom-control>` and `<controls>` support `ngModel`, so they both have their own `ValueAccessor` which made `DynamicComponentLoader` problematic (can't just load the component.)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Sprinkling `forwardRef` doesn't seem to work for me.